# Truffle test: error when passing more than one file as input

Tags: truffle, javascript

I have several test files, which I can successfully execute via `truffle test` (having started a `ganache-cli` process).

For example:

- `ganache-cli`
- `truffle test test/test1.js`
- `truffle test test/test2.js`

However, when I try to input both files at once, for example:

- `ganache-cli`
- `truffle test test/test1.js test/test2.js`

Truffle completes the first one successfully, but throws an error for the second one:

```
Contract: Test2 "before all" hook: prepare suite:
Uncaught Error: Error: LevelUpArrayAdapter named 'blockLogs' index out of range: index 6; length: 6
at C:\Users\barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\cli.node.js:85357:23
at C:\Users\barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\cli.node.js:85331:5
at C:\Users\barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\cli.node.js:85777:12
at C:\Users\barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\cli.node.js:85542:19
at C:\Users\barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache-cli\build\cli.node.js:87681:7
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
...
```

Here is my `truffle-config.js` file:

```
// See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
module.exports = {
    contracts_build_directory: "./build/contracts",
    networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*", // Match any network id
            gas: 4712388, // Gas limit used for deploys
            gasPrice: 100000000000, // Gas price used for deploys
        },
    },
    solc: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 5000000,
        },
    },
};
```

Does anybody have any idea what I am missing here?

I found [this related thread](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1465) on GitHub, which gives the following explanation:

```
You throw an error that is unhandled.
Read the error message.
"Uncaught Error" means that something @#$% up and there was no one to clean up.
The program has no choice but to exit.
```

But it doesn't quite explain why everything works correctly when I `truffle test` one file at a time.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just made a try using the same methodology as you did and it seems to work on my side :

[image: Test]

The problem you're submitting might be an error of code in your unit tests. 
Could you provide the code of the files ?

Comment: I don't have `using network 'development'`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. However maybe playing with the params of your truffle-config and/or using the default one ( without the solc optimizer ) might give different result. 

Giving a try at that won't cost much and might help stepping forward in understanding why it fails.